# how to setup mongo mms for pc that is in local subnetwork?

Tags: mongodb

I have a ubuntu pc's in internal sub-network that I'm running mongo on them. This machines are inaccessible from outside my company network.
I've seen the http://www.10gen.com/mongodb-monitoring-service which allow me to monitor the mongo setup. But which ip should I add into this cloud service?

Does there exists some install file to be installed on my pc, to allow me the monitoring the mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMS monitoring agent will try to contact the MMS server on the internet and will push information in regular intervals, so there is no need to open listening ports.

The outbound connection [will try to address port 443](https://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html#install-the-mms-agent) (HTTPS), so the outbound connection should work by default in all but the most restrictive setups.

The MMS agent is written in python and requires some python-specific setup, but you can [follow the installer steps](https://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html) from the manual.

Comment: The MMS agent uses outbound https (port 443)